# In TSQL, how to check a string include "a" followed by "b", and "b" not followed by "c"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

In TSQL, how to check a string include "a" followed by "b", and "b" not followed by "c"? For example, these strings is what I want:

```
ab
cab
acb
```

This is not what I want:
    abc

Note that you can insert any number of characters between the characters in the example(but not break my rule described above).

Comment: It sounds like a relational database management system is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: How about the mix of that like abbc ?

Comment: Answers are getting a lot of down votes for details not in in the questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the SQL wildcard character `%` to define any characters (one or multiple) within a string, then combine it with the `LIKE` operator:

```
WHERE txtcol LIKE '%a%b%' AND txtcol NOT LIKE '%b%c%'
```

Comment: It is hard to see the rules from the question, but as I see it 'abdc' should break as 'b' is followed by 'c'.

Comment: Looks like you're right, per the OP's comment, 'abbc' should not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this without the like:

```
where charindex('a', string) < charindex('b', string) and
      charindex('c', string) < charindex('b', string)
```

If you need for the characters to be there, then include:

```
where charindex('a', string) < charindex('b', string) and
      charindex('c', string) < charindex('b', string) and
      charindex('a', string) > 0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
col1 like '%ab%' and col1 not like '%abc%'
```

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Alphabet contains "ab" not followed by "c", so it should match?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
WHERE string LIKE '%ab%' AND string NOT Like '%bc%'
```

Comment: Guess it depends on Yousui definition of followed by.   This works if he means a followed immediately by b and not b followed immediately by c.   So without clarification from Yousui, hard to say alphbet breaks or not...

Comment: "Note that you can insert any number of characters between the characters in the example(but not break my rule described above)."

Comment: "followed by" does not need to followed by immediately.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

> char letter = 'c';
>
> if (letter == 'z')
>       nextChar = 'a'; else if (letter == 'Z')
>       nextChar = 'A';
>
> else
>       nextChar = (char)(((integer) letter) + 1);

Comment: The poster specifically asked for T-SQL. This looks like some variation of C.